# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka - How to implement idempotency to support distributed transaction management (eventual consistency)

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices, distributed-transactions, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have the following typical scenario:

- An order service used to purchase products. Acts as the commander of the distributed transaction.
- A product service with the list of products and its stock.
- A payment service.

  ```
      Orders DB               Products DB
         |                       |
  ---------------         ----------------          ----------------
  | OrderService  |       | ProductService |        | PaymentService |
   ---------------         ----------------          ----------------
         |                       |                         |
         |                --------------------             |
         --------------- | Kafka orders topic |-------------
                         ---------------------
  ```

The normal flow would be:

1. The user orders a product.
2. Order service creates an order in DB and publishes a message in Kafka topic "orders" to reserve a product (PRODUCT_RESERVE_REQUEST).
3. Product service decreases the product stock one unit in its DB and publishes a message in "orders" saying PRODUCT_RESERVED
4. Order service gets the PRODUCT_RESERVED message and orders the payment publishing a message PAYMENT_REQUESTED
5. Payment service orders the payment and answers with a message PAYED
6. Order service reads the PAYED message and marks the order as COMPLETED, finishing the transaction.

I am having trouble to deal with error cases, e.g: let's assume this:

5. Payment service fails to charge for the product, so it publishes a message PAYMENT_FAILED
6. Order service reacts publishing a message UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION
7. Product service increases the stock in the DB to cancel the reservation and publishes PRODUCT_UNRESERVATION_COMPLETED
8. Order service finishes the transaction saving the final state of the order as CANCELLED_PAYMENT_FAILED.

In this scenario imagine that for whatever reason, order service publishes a UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION message but doesn't receive the PRODUCT_UNRESERVATION_COMPLETED message, so it retries publishing another UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION message.

Now, imagine that those two UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION messages for the same order end up arriving to ProductService. If I process both of them I could end up setting an invalid stock for the product.

In this scenario how can I implement idempotency?

**UPDATE:**

Following Artem's instructions I can now detect duplicated messages (by checking the message header) and ignore them but there may still be situations like the following where I shouldn't ignore the duplicated messages:

1. Order Service sends UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION
2. Product service gets the message and starts processing it but crashes before updating the stock.
3. Order Service doesn't get a response so it retries sending UNDO_PRODUCT_RESERVATION
4. Product service knows this is a duplicated message BUT, in this case it should repeat the processing again.

Can you help me come up with a way to support this scenario as well? How could I distinguish when I should discard the message or reprocess it?

Comment: How about this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver ?

Comment: Hi Artem, it looks good... I am using Spring Cloud Stream so it raises some doubts regarding the config. Is it as easy as adding the spring integration dependency and configuring the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`? I am using `@StreamListener(OrderProcessor.INPUT)` to annotate the handling methods. Will the `@IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")` annotation work OK on them?

Comment: Well, SCSt is fully based on Spring Integration. I'm not sure who says you something different. There are a lot of appropriate dependencies there already. No, that won't work with that annotation. But you can switch to `@ServiceActivator` with the same result for message, but idempotent receiver will work here.

Comment: Great! I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I have modified the code and can see the interceptor applied. However by default the messages have different id's (UUID). I tried setting one manually but it doesn't work:  
`MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg.getMessage().getBytes()).setH‌​eader(MessageHeaders‌​.ID, msg.getId()+"-"+msg.getState()).build();` Exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'id' header is read-only`. How can I provide a generated unique id? Regards

Comment: ??? You have to choose your own `idempotency key`. Don't rely on the Message ID.

Answer (score 2):

We used spring-integration-kafka to produce and consume messages with Kafka in our microservices. In our case, we send org.springframework.messaging.Message objects to topics and get the same type from topics after deserialization from byte-array. In Message entity there are message-id, sent-time etc. headers values other than message payload which is the actual object that you want to transfer from one microservice to others. We use unique message-id value to implement idempotency. On producer side, you must implement some logic to ensure that, the message-id of the Message is the same when it is produced multiple times. This is actually related to your produce logic. In our case, we use Publishing Events Using Local Transactions which is very well described in the blog https://www.nginx.com/blog/event-driven-data-management-microservices/ by Chris Richardson. With this approach we can recrate Message object with the same message-id on producer side. On consumer side, we persist all the consumed message id values to database and check this ids before processing the received messages. If we see a message whose id is in our persistent store, we simply ignore it.

In your case, To implement idempotency:

- you should keep a unique identifier with the messages,
- On producer side, you must generate the same identifier when it is produced multiple times,
- On consumer side, you must check the received id to detect whether it is consumed before or not

**Regarding to Second Scenario Which is Described in UPDATE,**

I think you should change your mind a little bit. If you want to implement publish-subscribe mechanism which is more suitable in microservices architecture, you shouldn't wait response on producer side. In this scenario, you wait other message to know whether the consumer consumed the message or not and if it is not consumed by the consumer, you send it again.

How about the implementation below;
On producer side, you send messages to Kafka within a transaction in producer. You should provide a mechanism here to send messages to kafka only the transaction on producer side is committed. This is Atomicity issue and i give a link above which shows how to solve this issue.

On Consumer side, you poll messages from kafka topic one by one in order and you get the next message only when the current message can be consumed. If it is not consumed, you shouldn't get the next message. Because the next message might be related to current message and if you consume the next message you may corrupt consistency of your data. Its not producer's concern when the message not consumed. On consumer side, you should provide retry and replay mechanisms to consume messages.

I think you shouldn't wait response on producer side. Kafka is a very smart tool, and with its offset commit capability, as a consumer you don't have to consume messages when you poll messages from topic. If you have a problem while processing messages, you simply don't commit offset to get next message.

With the implementation described above, you don't have a problem like "*How could I distinguish when I should discard the message or reprocess it?*"

Regards...

Comment: Hi Ali, generating a unique message-id for every messages would be easy but... how do you associate it to the message you send? I send the messages like this: `source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(order).build());` Where do you provide the unique id?. Regards

Comment: I tried setting a custom id with `MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg.getMessage().getBytes()).setHeader(MessageHeaders.ID, msg.getId()+"-"+msg.getState()).build();`But got an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'id' header is read-only`

Comment: `id` is a header used by Spring Integration. You can use a custom header instead - which you will need to configure on the `headers` property of the Kafka binder - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties

Comment: Yes, Marius is right. We add another custom header which is used as message-id. The header with key id is derived by the library itself.

Answer (score -1):

actually because of the complications you mentioned about organizing transaction over multiple micro services over Apache Kafka, I developed another concept and wrote a blog about it.

If you reach a state of complication that Kafka solution might not be feasible anymore, you might find it as an interesting read. It is too long to explain here but basically it uses a J2EE container fully with Micro Service principle and with full transaction support between the Micro Services with the help of the Spring Boot + Netflix.

[Micro Services Fanout and Transaction Problems and Solutions with Spring Boot and Netflix](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/micro-services-fan-out-transaction-problems-and-solutions-with-spring-bootjboss-and-netflix-eureka/)

Comment: Interesting post. However I don't think your solution is useful in most of our business infrastructures. We can't rely on having our microservices running on the same JVM 'cause they don't have to. What about scalability? Your solution isn't scalable and is not complatible with platforms such as Kubernetes or OpenShift. What's more, you say that if the JMX option fails you can fallback to REST without transactions... back to the initial problem.

Comment: As I mentioned in the blog, it is all about design and deployment decisions, One JVM is not enough for scaling, then start another one, that is the way we are doing it in years isn't it. Spring Cloud, Kubernetes, OpenShit are not doing anything else at the background, they are just starting new JVMs. As I wrote in the blog, the concept I wrote in the article are not direct alternative to Kubernetes, OpenShift, etc I am afraid classical businesses, banking, insurances, telekom, can't work on those environments, it just give tose industuries the possiblity of using Micro Service principles.